# Splice method in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) to add new `components` into an array. If I use `concat` all the elements are added properly at the end, but what I also need is add at the beginning or in the middle of the array using `splice`. Any suggest ?

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    components: []
  };

  addNewElement = (element) => {      
    this.setState(prevState => ({   
      //Works fine
      //components: prevState.components.concat(element)

      components: prevState.components.splice(0, 0, element)
    }));
  };

}
```

Comment: `splice` modifies the array inline; what you want is something that'll return a modified version of the array like `slice` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: splice will work, it just returns funky: an array of deleted items, not the array itself. do the splice() off to the side instead of capturing it's return and you'll be fine, or something like `prevState.components.splice(0, 0, element) && prevState.components` if you want it all inline. tack on `.slice()` if you want a fresh new array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be careful to note the difference between methods that mutate the array on which they are called and methods which returns mutated versions of the array on which they are called.

`prevState.components.splice(0, 0, element)` returns a new array containing the elements which have been removed, which for your purposes is going to be nothing.

Notably, `splice` also mutates the components array; mutating your State elements is A Bad Thing To Do; one simple way to avoid that is to create a clone of your array and splice *that*.

```
this.setState(prevState => {
  const components = prevState.components.slice(0);
  components.splice(0, 0, element);
  return { components };
});
```

This is functional, but relatively inelegant.

Other options you could consider would be to use React's [immutability helper](https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper) or use `slice` to divide your original array in two then `concat` all the bits together:

```
const i = // index at which to insert the new elements
const left = prevState.components.slice(0, i)
const right = prevState.components.slice(i)
return {
  components: left.concat(elements, right)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) returns an array of elements that have been removed from the array. If no elements were removed, `splice` will return an empty array.

However, `splice` will change the contents of the array it's called on. You need to set the state on the updated array, not on what `splice` returns.

Try this method:

```
addNewElement(element) {
  this.state.components.splice(0, 0, element);
  this.setState({ components: this.state.components });
}
```

Below is a working snippet to demonstrate how you can insert a new element at a selected index using `splice` within a React component.

[CodePen Demo](https://codepen.io/dankreiger5/pen/KvwBZN?editors=1010)

Answer (score 1):

`Array#splice` works *in situ* and mutates the original array. You have to make a new instance (copy it) with `Array#slice` and then modify it.

```
addNewElement = (element) => {
   const newArr = prevState.components.slice();   
   newArr.splice(2, 0, 'foo');         // add 'foo` string at `2nd` index
   this.setState(prevState => ({   
      components: newArr;
   }));
};
```