# Removing Deleted Record from Array State

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a process where the comments associated to a book record are stored in an array in a state and has actions to POST or DELETE an individual record and array element. I have the POST action working as intended and the DELETE API call working to delete my record from a database, but I'm not sure the best practice to search my array for the newly deleted record and to remove that value from the array or if I should trigger a refresh method for the React component to display the newly changed array.

**Parent state and functionality (question is related to `deleteCommentsFunc()`:**

```
class BookFeed extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
            comments: []
        };
        this.deleteCommentsFunc = this.deleteCommentsFunc.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
        console.log("componentWillReceiveProps");
        console.log(nextProps);
        let commentArr = [];
        nextProps.books.map((book) => {
            book.book_comments.map((comment) => {
                commentArr.push(comment);
            })
        })
        console.log(commentArr)
        this.setState({comments: commentArr});
    }

    deleteCommentsFunc(deletedComment){
        console.log(deletedComment);
        var updatedCommentArr = this.state.comments;
        var index = updatedCommentArr.indexOf(deletedComment.target.value);
        updatedCommentArr.splice(index, 1);
        this.setState({comments: updatedCommentArr});
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
            { 
                this.props.books.map((book, index) => {
                    return (
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 book-card-container">
                                <BookCard {...book} key={book.bookIdHash} user={this.props.user} />
                                <Comments comments={this.state.comments} key={index} bookId={book.bookIdHash} csrf={this.props.csrf} updateComments={this.updateCommentsFunc} deleteCommentFunc={this.deleteCommentsFunc} user={this.props.user.userId}/> 
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    );
                })
            }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**Child function calling DELETE and passing returned JSON (which is just a 1 indicating a successful delete):**

```
deleteCommentCall(bookId, bookCommentId, csrf){
        var body = { bookId: bookId, bookCommentId: bookCommentId };
        var route = 'http://localhost:3000/app/book/' + bookId + '/comment/' + bookCommentId;
        fetch(route, 
            { 
                method: 'DELETE', 
                body: JSON.stringify(body), 
                headers: { 
                    'X-CSRF-Token': csrf,
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
            .then(res => {
                return res.json();
            })  
            .then(data => {
                console.log(data);
                this.props.deleteCommentFunc(data)
                this.setState({'flash': 'success'});
            }) 
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
                this.setState({'flash': 'error'});
            });
    }
```

As you might be able to tell the parameter value `data`, which contains a 1 if DELETE was successful is not helpful in my `deleteCommentsFunc()`, and what I really need to have is a value that I can find within the array to be able to remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly calling [`splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) on `this.state` in React [is bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45313840/5566355) as it is a mutative method.

You could retain your current implementation by cloning your `comments` `array` using [`spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), rather than pointing to a [`reference`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value) of it.

```
// Comments.
const comments = [...this.state.comments]
```

Alternatively, you could utilize [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to achieve the same objective with less overhead.

```
deleteCommentsFunc(bookCommentId){

  // Filter Out Deleted Comment By Comparing Id.
  const comments = this.state.comments.filter((comment) => { 

    // bookCommentId.
    console.log('bookCommentId', bookCommentId)

    // comment.bookCommentId.
    console.log('comment.bookCommentId', comment.bookCommentId)

    // Compare.
    comment.bookCommentId != bookCommentId)
  }

  // Update State.
  this.setState({comments}) 
}
```

Please note: I have no idea what your `comment` schema is (I'm assuming they are `objects` with unique `id` props). You will have to pass the `bookCommentId` to the `deleteCommentsFunc()` when you call it and maybe adjust the `comment.id` reference therein to point to your `comment`'s actual `id` prop.

Comment: Arman thank you for your detailed answer. I believe your note at the end of your answer is very relevant to the problem I face with using your `deleteCommentsFunc()`. I have the passed the deleted ID to the function and is stored as `bookCommentId`, but my `comment.bookCommentId` is not matching so the array does not change. Here is the Schema from my JSON: `{bookCommentId: 4, bookId: 5, comment: "This is a test"}`. Shouldn't `comment.bookCommentId` be the correct reference? Is there a way to see what `comment` is referencing out of the `.filter()` method?

Comment: Yes mate, that is correct. `bookCommentId` should be compared with  `comment.bookCommentId`. See my revised answer for an example of how to log the `filter()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the update, the logging has been helpful in seeing the array being looped through each `comment.bookCommentId` and I see the Id that matched `bookCommentId`, but the `//Update State. this.setState({comments})` still shows the same array length as when the array started. I'm using `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` to load reload the state when a new record is added, should something happen here when a record is deleted in order to show the change of removing the record?

Comment: Disregard my comment above. It was because I was filtering on a variable set to `this.state.comments` rather than setting a variable to the output of the `.filter()`. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a comment ID, it is better to filter the comments array:
`filter` will return a new array.

```js
deleteCommentsFunc(deletedCommentID){
   var updatedCommentArr = this.state.comments;
   updatedCommentArr.filter(comment => comment.bookCommentId !== deletedCommentID)
   this.setState({comments: updatedCommentArr});
}
```

Inside `deleteCommentCall`, you can pass the ID: `this.props.deleteCommentFunc(bookCommentId)`